# Label only shows the first letter

Tags: swift, fonts

I've a label in my application, I've an extension so I can set what font I want including font size, shadow etc, but whenever I set that to my label it only shows the first letter only

```swift
public extension UILabel {
    func FontStyle(fontSize:Int,shadowRadius:CGFloat,shadowOpacity:Float,shadowX:Int,shadowY:Int,fontFamily:String){
        self.font = UIFont(name: fontFamily, size: CGFloat(fontSize))
       self.layer.masksToBounds = false
       self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
       self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
       self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowX, height: shadowY)
    }
}
    @IBOutlet weak var LoginLabel: UILabel!
    LoginLabel.FontStyle(fontSize: 64, shadowRadius: 4, shadowOpacity: 0, shadowX: 0, shadowY: 4, fontFamily: "QuickSand")
```

I don't understand what the problem is, as you can see I use Custom font called `Quicksand`

Comment: Have you shrunk the font size? I assume it's too big and the label is truncating the text

Comment: That was the problem, Thank you for your solution @Jake